# How to build a jtree dynamically

Tags: java, swing, dynamic, jtree

The SSCCE of the problem is as follows. I am dynamically populating `JTree`, but nothing is happening.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

public class DynamicTreeDemo extends JFrame
                        implements ActionListener {
private int newNodeSuffix = 1;
private static String ADD_COMMAND = "add";
private static String REMOVE_COMMAND = "remove";
private static String CLEAR_COMMAND = "clear";

private JTree jtrMainMenu;
DefaultMutableTreeNode   rootNode = null;
DefaultTreeModel treeModel;
public DynamicTreeDemo() {
    super(new BorderLayout());

    //Create the components.
    jtrMainMenu = new JTree();
    populateTree();

    JButton addButton = new JButton("Add");
    addButton.setActionCommand(ADD_COMMAND);
    addButton.addActionListener(this);

    JButton removeButton = new JButton("Remove");
    removeButton.setActionCommand(REMOVE_COMMAND);
    removeButton.addActionListener(this);

    JButton clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
    clearButton.setActionCommand(CLEAR_COMMAND);
    clearButton.addActionListener(this);

    //Lay everything out.
    jtrMainMenu.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 150));
    add(jtrMainMenu, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,3));
    panel.add(addButton);
    panel.add(removeButton); 
    panel.add(clearButton);
add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}


    public void populateTree() {
  Vector<Vector<String>> data =GetDataFromDB();           
 java.util.List<String> list =GetListFromDB();
        int i=0;;
 int size=list.size();
 treeModel=(DefaultTreeModel)jtrMainMenu.getModel();  

 ((DefaultMutableTreeNode)  (treeModel.getRoot())).removeAllChildren();
 treeModel.reload();
 rootNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("JewelleryERPApplication");
 treeModel=new DefaultTreeModel(rootNode);


 DefaultMutableTreeNode p1=null, p2=null,p3=null,p4=null,p5=null;


     while(i<size){

        if(list.get(i).length()==2){
          p1 = addObject(null, data.get(i).elementAt(1),true);  

        }else 
        if(list.get(i).length()==4){
           p2 = addObject(p1, data.get(i).elementAt(1),true);   

     }else if
       (list.get(i).length()==6){
             p3 = addObject(p2, data.get(i).elementAt(1),true);   

     }
     else if
       (list.get(i).length()==8){
             p4 = addObject(p3, data.get(i).elementAt(1),true);    

     }  
     else if
       (list.get(i).length()==10){
             p5 = addObject(p4, data.get(i).elementAt(1),true);    

     }      
         i++;
     }

    jtrMainMenu.setModel(treeModel);
   ((DefaultMutableTreeNode)  (treeModel.getRoot())).getChildCount();
    jtrMainMenu.revalidate();
    jtrMainMenu.repaint();
}


public DefaultMutableTreeNode addObject(DefaultMutableTreeNode parent,
                                        Object child, 
                                        boolean shouldBeVisible) {


          DefaultMutableTreeNode childNode = 
            new DefaultMutableTreeNode(child);



    if (parent == null) {
        parent = rootNode;
    }

//It is key to invoke this on the TreeModel, and NOT DefaultMutableTreeNode
    treeModel.insertNodeInto(childNode, parent, 
                             parent.getChildCount());

     jtrMainMenu.setModel(treeModel);

    //Make sure the user can see the lovely new node.
    if (shouldBeVisible) {
        jtrMainMenu.scrollPathToVisible(new TreePath(childNode.getPath()));
    }

    return childNode;
} 

/**
 * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
 * this method should be invoked from the
 * event-dispatching thread.
 */
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("DynamicTreeDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Create and set up the content pane.
    DynamicTreeDemo newContentPane = new DynamicTreeDemo();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: I'd start by having a look at `rootNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("JewelleryERPApplication");` in your `addObject` method

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: even after removing this statement nothing happens @MadProgrammer

Comment: This `jScrollPane_Tree.removeAll();`  also worries me, it's likely you've actually removed the `JViewport` in the process

Comment: Now i also remove that part @MadProgrammer

Comment: See [`DynamicTreeDemo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#eg).

Comment: i am using the same example @trashgod

Comment: I see significant differences; the demo has two files.

Comment: i have merged the code of DynmaicTreeDemo and DynamicTree, have tried using the object DynamicTree but nothing was happended, i debugged but in the end my tree showed zero nodes.

Comment: A number of things come to mind.  If possible, make sure that the root node is visible, it's handle is visible and that you expand it once it's loaded

Comment: Your code `extends JFrame`; the tutorial `extends JPanel` and actually `implements ActionListener`. Where is `actionPerformed()`?

Comment: @trashgod Add adding a window to window...

Comment: And copyright violation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of problems with you code, but...the major problem (I think) you're having is the fact that when you reload the model, the root node is collapsed by default.

If the root node is hidden and/or it's handle is hidden, it will appear as if nothing has been loaded.

Unhide these elements for testing.

You can also expand the root node once the model has been reloaded...

[image]

**!! Warning !!** Don't run this on your root directory !! It will scan all child directories and that could take more time then you're actually willing to wait for :P

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

public class FileTree {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FileTree();
    }

    public FileTree() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private DefaultTreeModel model;
        private JTree tree;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            tree = new JTree();
            File rootFile = new File(".");
            DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(rootFile);
            model = new DefaultTreeModel(root);

            tree.setModel(model);
            tree.setRootVisible(true);
            tree.setShowsRootHandles(true);

            add(new JScrollPane(tree));

            JButton load = new JButton("Load");
            add(load, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            load.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) model.getRoot();
                    root.removeAllChildren();
                    model.reload();
                    File rootFile = (File) root.getUserObject();

                    addFiles(rootFile, model, root);

                    tree.expandPath(new TreePath(root));

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void addFiles(File rootFile, DefaultTreeModel model, DefaultMutableTreeNode root) {

            for (File file : rootFile.listFiles()) {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(file);
                model.insertNodeInto(child, root, root.getChildCount());
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    addFiles(file, model, child);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Code Review**

You should avoid extending directly from `JFrame`. From the looks of you example, you weren't, but hacked it in, but it's inadvisable anyway...

This...

```
jtrMainMenu.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 150));
add(jtrMainMenu, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

This is inadvisable.  `JTree` should be added to `JScrollPane`.

This...

```
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("DynamicTreeDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Create and set up the content pane.
    BadTree newContentPane = new BadTree();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Isn't going to work either (based on your example), as anything that extends from `Window` can not be added to any other container that extends `Window`

Unless your base component is extending from `JComponent`, must other components are opaque (`JLabel` is an obvious exception), so setting the `newContentPane` to opaque may be a mute point.

Comment: Thanks that works for me, Thank You @MadProgrammer you are a great swing guru (:-

Comment: @SyedMuhammadMubashir I wouldn't say that, I've just done the same thing before and spent four hours trying to figure out why :P

Comment: As far as scanning the file system root, you also have the option of lazily initializing the children for a tree node. This means you don't need to actually list a directory until a user expands the toggle for it.

Comment: @SamBarnum Yes, you could, it's also rather complicated ;)