# How to add new element under existing element in jlist using java swing?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, mouseclick-event

I,m using jlist to display my database data. The process works fine with fetching data from database and displaying in jlist element. I need to display my data under a jlist element by a click event. Example: Jlist containing user names, once i click the particular user it should display the attributes of the user below the jlist element.

Suggest me, if there is a way to do this process or it is not possible to display under a particular jlist element.

Thanks-in-advance.

Comment: Use a `JTable` or `JTree` - better structures for what you're trying to do

Comment: What do you mean with 'display under a jlist element'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Arunachalam  This is example of tree node contain images by using `DefaultTreeCellRenderer`.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;

public class DatabaseTree implements TreeSelectionListener {

  JFrame frame;
  DefaultTreeModel treeModel;
  DefaultTreeCellRenderer cellRenderer;
  JScrollPane pane;
  JTree tree;
  Connection connection;
  PreparedStatement pst;
  ResultSet rs;
  List<String> databaseNode = new ArrayList<String>();

  public DatabaseTree() {
    // JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
    root.setUserObject(new JLabel("Databases", new ImageIcon("/images/g.jpg"), JLabel.CENTER));
    treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
    try {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ganesh", "root",
          "admina");
      pst = connection.prepareStatement("show databases");
      rs = pst.executeQuery();
      while (rs.next()) {
        String text = rs.getString(1);
        databaseNode.add(text);
        root.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new JLabel(text, new ImageIcon("/images/g.jpg"),
            JLabel.CENTER)));
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    tree = new JTree(treeModel);
    tree.setCellRenderer(new MyTreeCellRenderer());
    tree.addTreeSelectionListener(this);
    tree.setRootVisible(true);
    tree.expandRow(0);
    pane = new JScrollPane(tree);
    frame.setContentPane(pane);
    frame.setVisible(true);

  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new DatabaseTree();
  }

  @Override
  public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) e.getPath().getLastPathComponent();
    String text = ((JLabel) node.getUserObject()).getText();
    JLabel label = null;
    if (databaseNode.contains(text)) {
      if (node.getChildCount() == 0) {
        try {
          pst = connection.prepareStatement("show tables in " + text);
          rs = pst.executeQuery();
          while (rs.next()) {
            String data = rs.getString(1);
            label = new JLabel(data);
            node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(label));
          }
        } catch (Exception ee) {
          ee.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  class MyTreeCellRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {

    JLabel label;

    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected,
                                                  boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row,
                                                  boolean hasFocus) {

      DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) value;
      label = (JLabel) node.getUserObject();

      if (selected) {
        label.setBackground(backgroundSelectionColor);
        label.setForeground(textSelectionColor);
      } else {
        label.setBackground(backgroundNonSelectionColor);
        label.setForeground(textNonSelectionColor);
      }
      return label;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How to reload jtree. @Ganesh

Comment: @Arunachalam I have no idea about to reload the tree.Try this is  remove all node and then add it again with your new data.

Comment: how to do it from one jframe to another.? Removing all node and displaying new data on button click from another frame. I'm creating new database and table in another frame form and it should display after button event ends.

Comment: Two frame means one is Dialog(Child frame) and Another is JFrame(Parent frame).So you want to reload the tree of JFrame(Parent) from Dialog(child) on button click. Am i understand right

Comment: yes, from child frame to parent frame. When i click child frame button the tree should reload on parent frame.

Comment: On action listener of button in JDialog you have to remove all Node from tree except the root node.And  make a method of stuff that we do in constructor for loading databases. Call this method in ActionListener of JDialog.

Comment: i produced the result into jtable. But, how to do selected database table should be resulted into jtable. It should get the database and table name from selection event and display the result on jtable without any button, just in click event, the process must work. Any suggestion?

Comment: On click event  you just check the node is table node by using `node.getChildCount() == 0`. Then get the name of table from node prepare a method that get the all table data create a `DefaultTableModel` using the `ResultSet`.After this set new `TableModel` on your display table.

Answer (score 3):

One of the first things you'll want to do is always first the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) and [tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) as they more often then not, have examples of how this would be done.

So, you need to now the index of the element based on the `MouseEvent` (or `Point`). Fun enough, while browsing the `JList` JavaDocs, I stumbled across this example...

```
 MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
         if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
             int index = list.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
             System.out.println("Double clicked on Item " + index);
          }
     }
 };
 list.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
```

Okay, good, we know of the index of the element in the `JList`, we can use [`ListModel#elementAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#elementAt-int-) to get the physical element, which you could use to query the database, look up the properties, or, if you've done it correctly and embedded an actually object into the model, get the attributes.

The only way to add elements dynamically to a `JList`/`ListModel` is through a mutable `ListModel`, like `DefaultListModel`.

Having said all that, both the `JTable` and `JTree` would be far better components to display compound information.

Comment: Maybe i could do as per your suggestion, moving for jtree to display my data.

Comment: It would be generally simpler. Alternatively, you could display additional information an a second form, so when the user clicks on a element in the `JList`, the information is loaded and displayed on a different panel

Comment: how to fetch database data and display it on jtree. To change root node as well as child node.

Comment: Are you want to fetch the databases as node and there tables as it child node

Comment: @Arunachalam Static trees are easier then dynamic trees, if possible pre load the data you need up front

Comment: @Arunachalam [This is an example of a dynamic `JTree`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215578/how-to-build-a-jtree-dynamically/15216070#15216070), it's based on listing files/directories, but the concept is the same

Answer (score 1):

This is working example of dynamic tree that load databases as node and their tables as child node.First you have to create a `root` node that contain the all node of databases, then after hide the root node this gives you feeling of list of databases.After that when we click on any database node  it load its tables dynamically in tree(Note: it load tables only when the database node is clicked)

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;

public class DatabaseTree implements TreeSelectionListener {

  JFrame frame;
  DefaultTreeModel treeModel;
  DefaultTreeCellRenderer cellRenderer;
  JScrollPane pane;
  JTree tree;
  Connection connection;
  PreparedStatement pst;
  ResultSet rs;
  List<String> databaseNode = new ArrayList<String>();

  public DatabaseTree() {
    // JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
    root.setUserObject("Database");
    treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
    try {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ganesh", "root",
          "admina");
      pst = connection.prepareStatement("show databases");
      rs = pst.executeQuery();
      while (rs.next()) {
        String text = rs.getString(1);
        databaseNode.add(text);
        root.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(text));
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    tree = new JTree(treeModel);
    tree.addTreeSelectionListener(this);
    tree.setRootVisible(false);
    tree.expandRow(0);
    pane = new JScrollPane(tree);
    frame.getContentPane().add(pane);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new DatabaseTree();
  }

  @Override
  public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) e.getPath().getLastPathComponent();
    String text = (String) node.getUserObject();
    if (databaseNode.contains(text)) {
      if (node.getChildCount() == 0) {
        try {
          pst = connection.prepareStatement("show tables in " + text);
          rs = pst.executeQuery();
          while (rs.next()) {
            String data = rs.getString(1);
            node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(data));
          }
        } catch (Exception ee) {
          ee.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATED**
For click event on tree node you have to add mouseListener on it

```
 tree.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        TreePath treePath = tree.getPathForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (treePath != null)
          String text = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode)treePath.getLastPathComponent()).getUserObject();
          txtField.setText(text);
            else
         txtField.setText("");
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: @Arunachalam Did you get your answer

Comment: what is the use of default tree cell renderer

Comment: How to create List<String> databaseNode = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: It works with displaying databases. But click event is not displaying tables.

Comment: Thanks @Ganesh Patel for your assistance, it works fine.

Comment: Suggest me how to do click event for each node. @Ganesh

Comment: clicking on leaf node, do action performed. Getting name of the node to display it in textfield. Not getting location of path. Is it possible?

Comment: @Arunachalam Yes it is possible you can get the element using `TreePath` by calling `getLastPathComponent()` on it.you can see the update in code

Comment: Actually in my answer there is no use of `DefaultTreeCellRenderer`. Using this you can create your own node that contain images as you like and also text.

Comment: Sorry @Ganesh, it has been clicked off when clicking mouse to active window.

Comment: i tried out with adding image icon to root node and child node. While doing the table icon is not showing and whenever i open and close the icon changes dynamically. How to set standard icon for three of them. Root Node Databases, showing databases with icon and showing tables with icon which should not differ on click event. Suggest me a solution.

Comment: @Arunachalam Use `DefaultTreeCellRenderer` for placing a icon on root node or other node